# Postgres: I'm trying to copy a table to a file it shows "Permission denied"

Tags: postgresql

I like to copy a table to a file i  postgresql

I tried this query

```
 COPY demo TO '/home/rck/Desktop/trial.csv'
```

But it shows permission denied

I also tried \copy but it shows syntax error

```
 \COPY demo TO '/home/rck/Desktop/trial.csv'
```

The error is

"**ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: \COPY demo TO '/home/rck/Desktop/trial.csv**

I also tried this command in terminal

```
chmod a+rX /home/rck/ /home/rck/desktop /users/rck/desktop/trial.csv
```

But it still shows the same error.

May I know the solution how to copy a postgres table to a file?

Thanks

Comment: Are you certain you ran these commands from psql using the -u and -d flags to be connected as a user with the required permissions granted? the \copy command should work.

Comment: I'm new to postgresql. How can I do this? I'm also a superuser in postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COPY demo TO '/home/rck/Desktop/trial.csv'` is serverside command - should be run as superuser and permissions to be set for user `postgres` on SERVER SIDE.

`\COPY demo TO '/home/rck/Desktop/trial.csv'` is client side `psql` command - can't be run from `pgAdmin` or so... and accordingly permissions on file path should be granted for the user you run `psql` with, not postgres...

Answer (score 1):

You will want to run the following commands. I would recommend putting them into a *.sql file and save it somewhere in the project for your reference. Change any  to your liking. Assuming though that you have created a database and the table demo inside it, the commands you need are:

```
create user <demouser> with password '<password>';
grant all privileges on database demo_db to <demouser>;
```

Then you can launch postgres with the psql command. Depending on your OS these will change slightly. For windows there is a -u command to set the user, but on linux it is done using sudo:

```
sudo -u <superusername> psql -d <demo_db>;
```

where if you used defaults  is likely postgres and  is the database that holds your table demo.

Then, after this command you should see the prompt

```
demouser=#
```

So then run

```
\copy demo to 'filename';
```

Comment: Thanks for reply it works good.  I'm executing this command in terminal in ubuntu. Is this possible to execute in postgres or pgadmin3 like a query because I want to set this as a trigger. Is this is possible?

Comment: It can be done just as anything else using the COPY command as a trigger. But from the documentation, 

Do not confuse COPY with the psql instruction \copy. \copy invokes COPY FROM STDIN or COPY TO STDOUT, and then fetches/stores the data in a file accessible to the psql client. Thus, file accessibility and access rights depend on the client rather than the server when \copy is used.

So you will need to configure the COPY command. Though I haven't tested it, I believe it is possible to use the COPY command in a trigger function just like any other trigger.